# Vue Testing Library: How to mock Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, vue-testing-library

I used React Testing-Library, but not Vue Testing-Library before https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro/ and I don't want to use mount or shallowMount where I can provide a stub. I want to figure out how to do that in VTL.

We usualy have components that use other components. So when testing our component say `ComponentA` it may use `ComponentB` and `ComponentC`. While there are some components that we want to be rendered (ComponentA and ComponentB) and want to test how they interact with our component, there are also others (ComponentC), which we may not want to test here, because they have their own tests. I.e. we want to "shallow-render" ComponentC when testing ComponentA.

Using react testing library we can do this:

```
import * as mockedComponentCModule from '....ComponentC';

jest.spyOn(mockedComponentCModule, 'ComponentC').mockImplementation(() => (
    <div data-testid="mocked-component-c" />
));
```

or I like this

```
jest.mock('path/to/my/ComponentC', () => ({
    ComponentC: function ComponentC() {
        return <div data-testid="mocked-component-c" />;
    }
}));
```

So in react when we do `render(<ComponentA />)` the `ComponentC` will render as a simple `div` instead of the actual component.

My question is - how can I do this with [Vue Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/vue-testing-library/intro)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this error \[Vue warn\]: Unknown custom element: <nuxt-link> in unit testing with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603780/how-to-fix-this-error-vue-warn-unknown-custom-element-nuxt-link-in-unit-te)

Comment: Nope. I want to use vue-testing-library, which uses `render`. I don't want to use `mount` or `shallowMount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `stubs`.

With vue testing library you can do this:

```
const wrapper = render(Component, { stubs: { ComponentToStub: true } }
```

Or instead of true you could also provide a string I think.

Comment: So the alternative to solution, provided by me, would be 

`const wrapper = render(Component, { stubs: { ComponentC: '<div data-testid="mocked-component-c">Test Content</div>' } });`

Comment: Both solutions work, but yours seem to be more concise and feeling more appropriate to the task at hand. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:

```
jest.spyOn(mockedComponentCModule.default, 'render').mockImplementation((create) =>
    create('div', { attrs: { 'data-testid': 'mocked-component-c' } }, 'Test Content')
);
```

Now sure if there's a better way - I'd be thankful if someone points me in the right direction

Comment: Accepting my answer since I didn't get any better suggestion.